# Commenting not working on FireFox

Tags: support, comment

I am not sure what happened (perhaps an upgrade in FireFox) but the commenting system completely stopped working in FireFox.

The FireFox version is: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US; rv:1.9.2.10) Gecko/20100914 Firefox/3.6.10 ( .NET CLR 3.5.30729)

The things that don't work

- Add Comment: Clicking on it does not bring up the textbox to add a comment.
- Show more comments: Clicking on it does not expand.
- Cannot upvote comments. Hovering near the comment does not show the clickable upvote comment.

I am also unable to upvote/downvote answers/questions.

I haven't tried posting an answer yet, so don't know if that is not working too (my guess is it will work fine, as this looks like a Javascript issue).

Here is an error shown by the Javascript error console:

```
Error: vote is not defined
Source File: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5617/party-planning-problem
Line: 46
```

And this is a warning:

```
Warning: The 'charCode' property of a keyup event should not be used. The value is meaningless.
Source File: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5617/party-planning-problem
Line: 0
```

A refresh does not help.

I didn't try deleting the cached js files, yet.

Strangely enough, on a different computer (different OS version altogether) with the same firefox version, it works: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.10) Gecko/20100914 Firefox/3.6.10

I suppose it is something local...

Comment: Have you tried doing a shift-reload, which does some cache-clearing without having to dig around in the cache or clear it entirely?

Comment: I tried shift+reload. Does not seem to work.

Comment: @Moron: Can you load http://sstatic.net/js/question.js?v=e24dbefef57d ?

Comment: @Kenny: I will let you know in about 8-9 hours. I am away from that computer currently.

Comment: @Kenny: No, I can't load that page using the computer that is giving me problems: Content Encoding Error. "The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because it uses an invalid or unsupported form of compression."

Comment: @Moron: [Try clearing the cache](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Clearing_the_cache).

Comment: @Kenny: Apparently I didn't have to! It works now. Perhaps if you will care to add your comment as an answer, then I can tick that. I suppose this is not just local to me, based on the upvotes to my comment about not being able to load it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes the browser will cache an invalid Javascript / CSS file. You could try to completely clear the disk cache to force it download the correct version.

For Firefox, see http://kb.mozillazine.org/Clearing_the_cache.

Answer (score 0):

I also had unusual experience with comments today:

Edits to a comment on meta, within the time limit, were denied with the error "you can only edit comments every 5 seconds" (or whatever the allowed frequency), although the time between posting and editing was more than that, and I experimented with longer delays but was denied in all cases.

This is in Firefox 3.6.9 on Mac OS X.